# webtest, web application projects, and tfsbuild

Tags: tfsbuild, wap

I have a web application project (wap) that is successfully being deployed to a development server by our tfsbuild server.

I'd like the build server to run our collection of webtests after deployment.

What is a best practice (or ANY practice) for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution involved copying the website to the development server during the beforetest target.

Once that was done I ran the webtests which had been recorded against that server.

I guess the answer is, build it, deploy, record your tests, then add the tests to the build process.

Answer (score 0):

I use NAnt to do this, although with Cruise Control not tfs. Does tfs support nant? if so i'ts really easy to write the targets to get everything building and tested, where failed tests => failed builds